# How can you save the queue for ThreadPoolExecutor so that you can resume after restart?

Tags: java, spark-java

I'm trying to develop an app using [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) (the web framework) and I will need to process some things in the background (async) so I don't block the user.

For this I'm thinking of using ThreadPoolExecutor. Is there a way to save the queue and resume later? (Maybe the app is stopped/restarted while the queue still has items in it).

Also how can you report the progress to the user (pending, in progress, done)?

Basically what I'm looking for is something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) but for Java and it needs to be embeddable in my app so the user won't need to install additional services.

Answer (score 1):

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` class provides a method called getQueue() that exposes the queue.

You should then be able to reuse the queue object (and its contents) when you create a new executor after the old one has been shut down.

Another possibility is to implement your executor suspend / resume by using a custom queue class that you can cause to block and unblock externally.  That has the advantage that the pools threads don't need to be destroyed / recreated when you suspend and resume your executor.

Comment: Are you attempting to preserve the unfinished work out there in async land so if the overall app stops (leaves memory, etc).. and gets restarted later.. you want to replay the outstanding work to a new ThreadPool?